# Rails - bcrypt_ext.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i just swapped over to mac and i am attempting to set up all my environments again. i am running 10.6.8 on snow leopard starting with rbenv i installed 1.9.3-p392 and 1.9.3-p327, i then installed sql server and then ran bundle after all the gems installed i tried creating the databases `bundle exec rake db:create` it then exploded

```
/Users/robpaulo/gems/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
```

i read that error is likely caused by ruby or by rbenv so i swapped the ruby version and rehashed rbenv and the same error occurs..

its the longest persisting error i have tackled and all the articles on it are vague